# SQL Server 2005 - content of variable is lost upon

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, variables, coalesce

I'm using SQL Server 2005 and have the following T-SQL statement:

```
DECLARE 
    @MP VARCHAR(500)
SELECT
    @MP = COALESCE(@MP + ',','') + [Name] + ',' + '(' + [Political Party] + ')'
FROM [MPs]
WHERE [MPs].[Region] ='Wales' 


UPDATE myTable
SET [Names and parties] = 
(SELECT @MP
WHERE myTable.[Local Region] ='Wales')
```

This works fine and will populate myTable with @MP where 'Wales' is present; however if I run the statement again, this time with say 'Scotland', all the previously updated entries for 'Wales' will then become NULL in myTable.

I think I'm missing something here - using a different variable name for @MP for the second search doesn't work.

Comment: You have `'Wales'` twice in your query. Have you updated it to `'Scotland'` in both places?

Comment: Hi Oded, I have - whenever I run this query I would update both values to be the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're probably looking for this:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET [Names and parties] = @MP
WHERE myTable.[Local Region] = 'Wales'
```

Comment: Thanks Pondlife and @SQL Dabbler!

Answer (score 2):

The second WHERE clause is in the wrong place.  It currently applies to the SELECT, rather than the UPDATE, which I think is what you want.

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET [Names and parties] =  @MP 
WHERE myTable.[Local Region] ='Wales'
```